# General combination and permutation (counting) in statistics

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations, combinations

so i'm studying for my last final which is statistic, been doing a lot of exercices, but the only part i'm having difficulty with is the counting/combinations/permutations problems.

My question precisely is what are the clues in a given problem on what formula to use to find the counting probability, such as white/red ball, x people are sitting to each other how many etc. It's like every problem i start has a new way of finding it's probability and i don't know how to approach them.

I know this is a really vague question, but i would really appreciate it if you could give me tips on how to approach these problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand how you feel about combinatorics problems. And yes, while there's a pattern to what techniques are generally tested, every question requires different strategy. I just finished my A Level earlier this month so I understand how you feel about combinatorics question that I too am scared of in exam setting.

I can't give you exact steps or anything of that sort but these are things you should look for when approaching such questions:

1. Does the order matter? Is permutation needed? Is combination alone sufficient?
2. Are the items distinguishable? Are there repeated items? Account for that.
3. Can you create smaller subgroups from the items so that the counting becomes easier? Handle each restriction one by one if possible. Maybe in $n$ items you make a smaller group of $k$ items that can be treated as 'one' item. This will prevent confusions later on.
4. Are there cases you need to consider? Are there A LOT of cases? Can these cases be written in sigma notation to simplify working? Make sure that all your cases are **mutually exclusive**.
5. If the question is especially tough, write down what your working means at every step so that you can check your work. Think of a way you would arrange those items in real life. What's the most efficient way to do it?

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time Karn, just took a picture of this will be using this steps to practice my next problems, have a great day!